# GPL v2 のスクリプトを改変した場合の公開

Tags: github, ライセンス, gpl

GitHub で掲載している Ruby スクリプトがあり、それはある別の人が作成し GPL v2 で公開していたものを掲載者が修正したもののようです。

そこで気になったのは、以下の３点です。

1. `gpl.txt` がなく、ソースのヘッダに短い文書で GPL の旨を記載している
2. Copyright の文面(と製作者の名前)がオリジナルの人のそのままとなっていて、改変情報がない。
3. バージョンもオリジナルのもののまま。

疑問点は以下の通りです。

- 1.については、 `gpl.txt` は必ずしもなくてもいいでしょうか? 短い文面で GPL v2 に基づくとの記載はあります。
- 2.については、元々の製作者の名前を残しつつ、 Modified by... などで変更があった旨を記載するのがいいでしょうか?
- 3.についても、改変バージョンとして "v2.1.3-mod" のようなオリジナルのバージョンから変更したバージョンにする方がいいでしょうか?

自分が公開する立場になった時、ひっかかりそうな部分ががあったので質問しています。

Comment: フォークしてPR用にいくつかコミットしている段階だったりはしないですか？

Comment: @3100 コミットして1日程度なので、その可能性はあります。ただ、自分でコミットする場合、どういう修正が適切なのか知りたいと思っています。

Comment: オリジナルのソースコードがGithub上にない場合やforkしてもPRするつもりがない場合は @だいじん の回答通りの対応でよいかと思います。もし、Github上でforkしてPRするつもりのものであれば、また違った対応になるかと思います。

Comment: @KIDtheEuforia このあたりよく理解してないと変なことをしそうで危ないですね。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GPL v2であれば、ソースコード中に下記の文面を記載する必要があります。
※フリーソフトウェア財団の住所は時々変わるので注意してください。

```
Copyright (C) yyyy  name of author

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301, USA.
```

改変時には、変更した履歴（日時と名前）の記載が必須です。

バージョンについての規定はないですが（そもそも各人が勝手に付けているだけですし）、オープンソースであればやはりバージョンを別物にしておいたほうが、ユーザーにとっては親切かなと感じます。
そのバージョンをキーにソースを検索しに来る人もいると思いますので（自分もよく目安にします）。

ソース：

- http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0.ja.html
- http://www.opensource.jp/gpl/gpl.ja.txt

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
掲示いただいたGPLの文章については元々のソースのヘッダに記載がありました。この場合はgpl.txtは不要なのですね。

変更履歴はやはり必要でしょうね。

バージョンに関してもオリジナルのままにしない方がいいとのこと同じ意見です。