# GPL における Copyright 文の正しい記述の仕方は?

Tags: ライセンス, gpl

[GPL v2 のスクリプトを改変した場合の公開](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/5590/754) をみていました。

一応 accepted answer があり、その抜粋として、どのような copyright 文・ GPL 文が記載されるべきかの例がありましたが、結局、 copyright 文としての正しい記述の仕方が何なのかがわからずにいます。

質問

1. copyright (C) 2016 Taro Yamada の copyright 文がある GPL ソースコードがあった場合に、それを他の人(例: Jiro Suzuki)が改変して配布する場合でも、この copyright 文は不変("copyright (C) 2016 Taro Yamada" のまま) である必要がありますか？ (前提として、変更履歴などにおいて変更日時・変更者名をきちんと明記したとして)
2. 1 が真であったとして、 GPL なので、そのプログラムがどんどん進化していったとしても、最初の著作者が自ら copyright 文を変更・ないしその許可を下さないかぎり、 copyright 文は "copyright (C) 2016 Taro Yamada" のままですか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本家での質問を発見しました。 [License question: GPL copyright header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7432367/3090068)

そこでの回答は

- 例えば次のような copyright 文なら見たことがある。
- GPL が、改変されたものを配布する場合には、その旨を明示しなければならないと定めているからこのような記述を行っている（のだろう)

でした。

```
/*
* Copyright (C) 200?-200? Project
* based on code by ForkedProjectCopyrightHolder copyright (C) 200?-200? ForkedProject
* License: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html GPL version 2 or higher
*/
```